# How can I do the progress view with stepping?

Tags: ios, objective-c

now I am conducting a iOS app with objective-c. I need to have a process bar with stepping to indicate the user registration procedure. How can I do it as the pictures?

[image: The process view of Registry View]

[image: The process View of Registry View Controller]

Answer (score 1):

I have made a custom view to implement the step indicator. Use `CAShapeLayer` to draw the circle and line. Check detail here: https://github.com/chenyun122/StepIndicator

The effect is:
[image]
OR
[image]

If you want to replace the core point by number, you could folk this project and modify the class `AnnularLayer.swift` to implement that.

Comment: How can I apply it in different view Controller?

Comment: In each view controller, you add different StepIndicatorView, and set different step number. Like, register one controller, StepIndicatorView.currentStep = 1. And for register two controller, StepIndicatorView.currentStep = 2.

Comment: OK, I have finished this part! Thank you so much

Comment: @AndrewLeung, I updated the SDK to support numbers, please check it.

Comment: Is there any way I can use it Vertically? @YunCHEN

Comment: @Nij, yes, it supports vertical mode.

Comment: I am using your library but I am facing the following problem, for some reason the bar does not load well despite the fact that it establishes its constraints to the UIView in leading and trailing 20 so that the view remains with those limits but does not load well anyway. @YunCHEN

Comment: @dbenitobaldeon, thanks for using. I am checking the problem. And I will reply it on Github issue.

Answer (score -1):

If animation doesn't matter then you can used image.Change your image when you push view